# How to Use Material theme for API level 8

Tags: android, material-design

Google play Market App designed using material theme 
When i put my theme codes on values/styles.xml file it shows error like android:Theme.Material requires Minimum api 21 (current 8)

I am also tried putting my material theme code to values-21/styles 
but no changes occurred Please explain how to use material theme for gingerbread to kitkat

Thanks in Advance..!! :)

Comment: Try using library like this one https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: Set your target to API Level 21, and use the latest support library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android:Theme.Material requires API21.

It means that you have to compile with API21 your app, and you have to use this style only in the `values-v21` folder.

You can use the appcompat library to implement the Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices.

Take a look here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html